# Complex Image based Button Layout

Tags: swift, image, button, layout

I'm fairly new to programming in general, I'm trying to figure out how to create numerous buttons in a complex layout. My layout is basically a transparent PNG of a body cut into about 24 sections and I want each segment of the body to be a separate button.

I've tried a few layouts in the view controller. Setting up a ton of buttons overlaying an image (couldn't keep the layout straight when launching in the simulator) and I've tried giving the buttons images, I've tried large image sized buttons but I could only use the top most button.

Is there any way to do this, or is it going to need code to be doable?

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewController` or `UICollectionView` is a better choice for you. You can set the `UICollectionView`s background image and regard the cells as your buttons.

Here is a quick example.

```
import UIKit

class Collection: UICollectionViewController {

    private let cellId = "cell"

    override init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        if let l = layout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
            l.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
            l.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            l.scrollDirection = .Vertical
            l.footerReferenceSize = CGSize.zero
            l.headerReferenceSize = CGSize.zero
            let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
            let itemWidth = CGFloat(Int(screenWidth/4))
            l.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
        }
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        collectionView?.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    }

}

extension Collection{

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return cell
    }

}
```

If you want to add touch action to a cell.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out this code, is it saying that it takes an image and breaks it up into 4 quadrants?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally sent that before I finished typing... I'm unsure how this code will help in my situation, I have a very irregular (human body outlined) shape. Not very square. Is there a way to use this to designate exact points or vector shapes as buttons or PNG shapes? The code you posted may be going way over my head I'm worried I won't be able to figure this out. Or would it be most efficient to use this and break my image up into 80 of these blocks and designate a set as part of one button?  I would post an image but I'm unable.